# Where is the line of javascript causing my browser window to load a different location?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, browser, single-page-application

I am working in a large, complex AngularJS SPA that is new to me. During the loading of the application something happens that changes the location of the application to completely different location and forces the unloading of the page.

I don't know how to find the line of code that is causing this location change.

It is changing the the location to the root of the domain, so there are few clues in address of the new location.

I have tried capturing the `beforeunload` event and inspected the `event` argument for clues, but have not found any valuable information.

What tools are techniques can I use to determine what line of javascript code is triggering this event?

Comment: I don't know any fancy techniques, but my first port of call would be to search in the entire project for the string corresponding to the URL it redirects to. (VS Code certainly lets you do this easily, and I assume other editors do as well.)

Comment: If you can search all of the code at once, look for `$location`

Comment: you can try adding setter for e.g. location.href and set breakpoint there

Comment: @RobinZigmond thank you. In my particular case the url that it redirects to is the root domain, so I do not have any path to search for.